# Authenticate AngularJs app with Symfony2 API

Tags: angularjs, rest, symfony, authentication

I have this situation:

My AngularJs application main view is rendered using Symfony2 and Twig.

From then the Symfony serves as REST api.

This AngularjJS application is accessible via route http:/mysite.com/. The route / is protected by a firewall, so everyone should authenticate against SAML Identity provider, to access the angular application.

The api stands behind the route prefix /api.

How should I authenticate the REST calls comming from Angular, if I already have the user to authenticate in order to enter this site? Is the authentication even neccesary in this case?

Another firewall with custom auth provider using some unique token for the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you won't have to authenticate the user if the starting point of your application is behind the firewall. Once authenticated, all the future requests will have the correct cookies.

However, if you'll need to expose your API for some external clients, then you'd have to implement a different auth mechanism.